# Need to copy rows from one ws to another based of multiple values in one column

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm moving information from one sheet to another sheet based off of values in one column on the master sheet.  Right now the code pulls rows based off of one value in the source column, but I need to modify it to pull rows matching two values.  What I use now is

```
  'If value in column Y ends with "6100", copy to report sheet
        If c.Value Like "*6100" Then
```

Basically instead of just 6100 I need to pull *6100 and *6200. I don't know why I'm not getting it to work. Any simple way to modify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

Although running a AutoFilter flagging True if the last 4 digits match these two criteira may be more efficient timewise if your code takes a while

```
 If c.Value Like "*6100" Or c.Value Like "*6200" Then
 'do stuff
 Else
 'do other stuff
 End If
```

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks. Out of curiosity if I wanted to pull it off values that do not match would it just be an easy swap out of "Like" in the line there? Or another line below for 'If Not c.Value Then' type thing?

Comment: Thanks Jon :) I have updated my code to show a full test, the "negative" test to pull off the values that dont match would be in the "do other stuff" section

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out, it is embedding multiple conditional statements into the cell, evaluating the contents of one cell to produce the desired outcomes.

=IF(Q1087<=0.04167,"< 1 Hr",IF(AND(Q1087<=0.2083,Q1087>0.0416),"1 to 5 Hrs",IF(AND(Q1087<=0.4167,Q1087>0.208),"5 to 10 Hrs",IF(AND(Q1087<=1,Q1087>0.4167),"10 to 24 Hrs",IF(AND(Q1087<=2,Q1087>1),"1 to 2 Days",IF(AND(Q1087<=5,Q1087>2),"2 to 5 Days",IF(Q1087>5," > 5 Days","")))))))

Comment: Wuggles you appear to have posted this to the wrong question?